# LeetCode, Two Sums Python 3

Tags: python

Error: List of index out of range on line 9 
Tried a few alterations but still can't figure what's wrong. Help is appreciated.
Code:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        ans = []
        for i in nums:
            for j in nums:
                if i == j:
                    break
              **elif nums[i]+nums[j] == target:**
                    ans.append(i)
                    ans.append(j)
                j += 1
            i += 1
        return ans
```

Comment: what code have you used to call this function? What value of `nums` and `target` is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to iterate over the indices, not the values.  Change the `for` loops as follows.  Also get rid of the explicit increments of `i` and `j`.  The incremenets are handled by `range`:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        ans = []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(len(nums)):
                if i == j:
                    break
                elif nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                    ans.append(i)
                    ans.append(j)
        return ans
```

Adding `range` causes `i` and `j` to iterate over the list indices rather than the list values.

Note that you can eliminate the in-loop test for `i == j` by changing the inner range to start at `i+1`:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        ans = []
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i+1, len(nums)):
                if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                    ans.append(i)
                    ans.append(j)
        return ans
```

If you want to pair the indices in the list, you could replace the pair of `append` calls with:

```
ans.append((i, j))
```

This will append each pair as a single two-element `tuple`, rather than as two top-level list values.

You could also use `itertools.combinations` to handle the nested loop for you.  Here's a version that uses `itertools`, and also appends the results as pairs:

```
import itertools

class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        ans = []
        for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(nums)), 2):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                ans.append((i, j))
        return ans
```

Although looking at the problem description, it says there will only be one solution, so you can really just return the first solution that you find:

```
import itertools

class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        for i, j in itertools.combinations(range(len(nums)), 2):
            if nums[i]+nums[j] == target:
                return i, j
        return None
```

Comment: Thanks... But an error still appears on line 6: List object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @Edkenzo Oops, sorry about that.  `range(nums)` needed to be `range(len(nums))` everywhere it occurred.  I've updated my answer.  Refresh the page and take a look.